# how to create folder in folder through .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have to take backup of a folder containing 3 folders using .bat file. The Structure is MainFolder\First Folder, MainFolder\Second Folder, MainFolder\Third Folder.  I want backup as MainFolder\30-04-2015\FirstFolder, MainFolder\30-04-2015\SecondFolder, MainFolder\30-04-2015\ThirdFolder.

MY .bat file containing -

```
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy% 

mkdir "Z:\MainFolder\%1%date%"

xcopy "C:\MainFolder\FirstFolder"  "Z:\MainFolder\%date%\FirstFolder"  /s/i
xcopy "C:\MainFolder\SecondFolder"  "Z:\MainFolder\%date%\SecondFolder"  /s/i
xcopy "C:\MainFolder\ThirdFolder"   "Z:\MainFolder\%date%\ThirdFolder" /s/i
```

Only date folder is created and no file is copied in it.

Please give solution.

Comment: Is the `%1` in this line a typo `mkdir "Z:\MainFolder\%1%date%"`?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to hate how hard to see your issue is!

You are setting date via `[SET date=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy% ]` The trailing space is included in the set command, so later the xcopy targets become `"Z:\MainFolder\05-01-2015 \FirstFolder"` - which of course doesn't exist and is invalid.

You can also simplify your date setting as follows:
`FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3,4 DELIMS= -" %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dt=%%A-%%B-%%C`
Note that I used dt instead of overwriting the built in date environment variable. You may have to switch %%A and %%B - as I think you are switching month and day around in your code. I'd normally name such a directory in yyyy-mm-dd format so that it sorts correctly.